# trouble installing accelerate-cuda

Tags: haskell, accelerate

I have been trying to run cabal install accelerate-cuda -fdebug to no avail. at first i had some issues i think with my version of cuda, so i upgraded ghc to version 8.0.1 and cabal to version 1.22.5.0.

I was able to run cabal install accelerate which worked but cabal install accelerate-cuda has resulted in :

> Resolving dependencies... cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
>   trying: accelerate-cuda-0.15.1.1 (user goal) next goal: base
>   (dependency of accelerate-cuda-0.15.1.1) rejecting:
>   base-4.9.0.0/installed-4.9... (conflict: accelerate-cuda => base>=4.7
>   && <4.9) rejecting: base-4.9.0.0, 4.8.2.0, 4.8.1.0, 4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2,
>   4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed instance) Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Answer (score 2):

Ghc 8.0.1 came with an updated version of base (4.9) which might be incompatible with the accelerate-cuda package.

You can try and pass the flag `--allow-newer` to cabal, or dowload the package with `cabal get` and edit the cabal fie manually setting `base >= 4.8 && <5.0` in the build dapends section.

Comment: thanks, i seem to have gotten it working via stack. But i guess now ghc and stack ghc are different versions... is this terrible?

Comment: --allow-newer did not work. Trying to manually set base. What is the best way to install after i do this? i am doing "runhaskell Setup configure" but there are missing dependencies...maybe i am not in the right place